# Space-like Killing vector of Robertson-Walker metric?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime

In the book "Kinetic theory in the expanding Universe" (J. Bernstein, 1988, Camb. Univ. Press), it was stated that

> "for nonstationary Robertson-Walker
>   matrixes [sic] there is no spacelike
>   Killing vector."

(page 6, footnote.)

But we know this is not true, since one can see that the generators of spatial translations/rotations are manifestly space-like. (For example, see R. Maartens and S.D. Maharaj, Class. Quantum Grav. 3 (1986) 1005-1011, equation (1.7)).

Was the author of the book wrong, or was it a slip of the hand, where "spacelike" should have been "timelike" (but that would amount to tautology anyway, since "nonstationary" is defined in terms of the absence of a time-like Killing vector).

Answer (score 3):

From the book by Kolb and Turner "The Early Universe", chapter 3.5:

> In the strictest mathematical sense it is not possible for the Universe to be in thermal equilibrium, as the FRW cosmological model does not possess  a **time-like** Killinig vector.

(Emphasis is mine). So it confirms the "slip of the hand" hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

The de Sitter metric 
$$
ds^2~=~dt^2~-~e^{\sqrt{\Lambda/3}t}(dr^2~+~r^2d\Omega^2)
$$
has this time dependent factor.  This prevents a time-like Killing vector, for any vector formed by $\sqrt{g_{rr}^{-1}}\partial/\partial t$, or something similar, will not constant on a timelike spacetime vector.  The same holds for spacelike directions, for space and time are interchangeable in $g_{rr}$.  This means global conservation laws are not defined.  Energy conservation in general relativity is a funny thing, and is not something which can be established.  In the case of cosmologies, these metrics FLRW etc, are type O Petrov-Penrose-Pirani solutions, which have no isometries or Killing vectors.

Comment: You can write the de-Sitter metric as $ds^{2}=-(1-\frac{1}{3}\Lambda)dt^{2} + \frac{dr^{2}}{1-\frac{1}{3}\Lambda}+r^{2}d\Omega^{2}$, which has an explicit timelike killing vector.  The coordinate transformation is easy--Let $r->Re^{\sqrt{\frac{\Lambda}{3}}\frac{t}{2}}$, and $t->T+f(R)$, where f(R) is chosen to cancel the cross-term.

Comment: True, but this is a special coordinate chart.  Also the metric term is $g_{tt}~=~(1~-~\Lambda x^2/3)$

Comment: @Lawrence: Yes.  typo.  But the Robertson-Walker-style expression of the metric is also a special coordinate charte--the true De-Sitter space doesn't have a $t=0$ singularity.

Comment: Both of you are writing metrics on a portion of the full de Sitter spacetime. Four-dimensional de Sitter has topology $R^1 \times S^3$ and is conveniently realized as a hyperboloid in $R^5$. Various combinations of the coordinates on the hyperboloid give the metrics above, but will only cover part of the hyperboloid. There may be timelike Killing vectors on the patches associated with those metrics, but there is no _global_ timelike Killing vector.

Comment: Exactly.  The solution in other coordinates or slicings  involves hyperbolic trigonometric functions.  The exponential form is a flat coordinate, and the form Schirmer uses are static coordinates.  There is no global timelike killing vector.

Comment: Thank you all for bringing my attention to the topic of global vs. local Killing vectors.